# Very very simple - CSS positioning -what am i doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, positioning

Help! I'm new to CSS/HTML and I can't understand what it is i'm doing wrong.

I want the three nav links on the right to be at the top of the page, but at the moment they are underneath the nav links on the left.

They are all within the `div.wrapper`, yet the `nav#menu2` doesn't seem to be a part of it?

Where am i going wrong?

Here's the HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h5 class="logo">TESTER SITE</h5>
        <nav id="nav_menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Mission & Background</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Objects, Vision & Values</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Staff Members</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Board Members</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </li>


                <li><a href="#">Our Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Training & Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Publications</a> </li>

            </ul>
        </nav>

        <nav id ="menu2">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service Providers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TW</a></li>

            </ul>


        </nav>

    </div>
</header><!--  End Header  -->
```

Here's the CSS:

```
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
vertical-align:baseline;

}







.feature a,
.cta a.cta_btn,
.testimonials #t_nav#nav_menuigation a,
header ul.social li a,
header nav#nav_menu ul li, header nav#nav_menu ul li ul, header nav#nav_menu ul li ul li a, header nav#nav_menu ul li:hover a {
transition:all .2s linear;
-webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
-moz-transition:all .2s linear;
-o-transition:all .2s linear;
}



/*  header  */


header{
width: 97%;
background: #e52929;
position:fixed;
z-index: 999;
box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 2px 1px #101010;
padding:0 1.5% 0 1.5%;



}



h5.logo{
float: left;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:2%;
font-size: 1.3rem;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; 
font-weight:700;  
text-transform: uppercase;
color:#fff;
margin-top:4px;
margin-bottom: 0;
position:relative;


}


header .menu_icon{
display: block;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
background: url('../img/menu_icon.png') no-repeat;
float: right;
margin-top: 23px;
display: none;
}




header nav#nav_menu{

width:65%;
position:;

}



header nav#nav_menu ul li {

font-size: 0.9em;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; 
font-weight:700;  
text-transform: uppercase;
padding:1% 1%;
margin: 0 auto;
display:inline-block;
text-align:left;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top: 0;


}

header nav#nav_menu ul ul {
position:absolute;
z-index:900;
visibility:hidden;   
background-color: #fff;
width:180px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:-8px;

padding:0;

}

header nav#nav_menu ul ul li {
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
z-index: -1;
padding:0;


}

header nav#nav_menu ul ul li a {
display:block;
padding:8% 10% 8% 5%;
margin-left:0;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; 
font-weight:700; 
width:100%;
color:#e52929;




}


header nav#nav_menu ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}



header nav#nav_menu ul li:hover{
background-color: #fff;
}



header nav#nav_menu ul li:hover a{
color: #e52929;
}


header nav#nav_menu ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
visibility: visible;
}


header nav#nav_menu ul li ul li:hover a {
background-color:#e52929;
color:white;

 }

header nav#menu2 {
position:relative;
float:right;
width:40%;
margin-top: 0;

}

header nav#menu2 ul {
list-style-type: none;
 }

header nav#menu2 ul li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 2%;
background-color: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px #101010;

 }

header nav#menu2 ul li:nth-child(4), header nav#menu2 ul li:nth-child(5) {


background-color: #525252;


}


header nav#menu2 ul li a:active, a:visited, a:link {
color:#e52929;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; 
font-weight:700;  
text-transform: uppercase;

}





/** {
   background: #000 !important;
  color: #0f0 !important;
  outline: solid #f00 1px !important;
}

 */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7zeLm1gu/

Comment: Thanks so much! Very kind of you to take the time to help.

Comment: Harry, are you going to accept one of the answers we kindly provided?

Answer (score 1):

You can add some float positioning to the menus: `float:left;`

Also, you need to adjust the percentage values for `header nav#nav_menu` and `nav#menu2`. The way you have it, they total up to `105%`.

So, you could do this with your existing code:

```
header nav#nav_menu,
header nav#menu2 {
  float:left;
}

header nav#nav_menu {
  width:45%;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1tctkzL7/1/show/)

Side note - you'll eventually want to use a [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/). If you look at the lists in your header, you'll see some default padding.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a combination of setting your widths correctly, and using floats. See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bdojLo46/)

I set floats:

```
#nav_menu, #menu2{float:left;}
```

and reduced the width of the first menu to 35% from 65%.

HTH,
-Ted

Comment: Thanks so much! Very kind of you to take the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

See your own stylesheet on:

```
header nav#nav_menu{

width:65%;
position:;

}
```

`position` is missing the value. you can remove the position.

Then, change manually in `#menu2`, as follows:

```
header nav#menu2 {
float:right;
width:40%;
margin-top:-17px;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Very kind of you to take the time to help.

Comment: I would help the best I can. Otherwise, you do that for me :D ... that's fair enough, right ? success for you